# Install DKMS on self-made Linux system

Tags: kernel-modules, dkms

I am trying to install DKMS on a Linux system that I made from the Linux from Scratch and Beyond Linux from Scratch books. I've found the package source from [here](http://linux.dell.com/dkms/) but absolutely no info as to how to install them. There's no configure file in the tar ball and the Makefile seems to expect either Debian or RPM, which I don't have. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: ok... I think I figured out hot to install this from source, but the Makefile seems to have some errors or maybe needs some tweaking. I'll try to fix it and post a patch on GitHub or somewhere. Please let me know if there is a better place to upload patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...so there's only one change to be made. This can be done in two ways:

1. Rename the directory in which the tarball is extracted as `dkms` instead of `dkms-2.2.x.x`. The Makefile expects that the tarball is unpacked in a directory called `dkms`.
2. Change the Makefile using the below `sed`:

   ```
   sed "s@\.\./\$\(RELEASE_NAME\) @\.\.\/\$\(RELEASE_STRING\) @" -i Makefile
   ```

Go with option 1 though. Much easier and safer.

After that DKMS can be installed using:

```
make tarball
sudo make install
sudo make install-doc
```